# Chart on Excel with grouped data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

In the image bellow, I have some data on columns Item, Type and Value. I would like to know how can I create a pie chart aggregated by the column `Type`. I mean, I would like just one slice for each type Office, Commerce, Store and Industry and the value would be the sum of each type. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Comment: A pivot chart may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pivot chart will allow you to display Type totals without showing two items of the same Type.

On the Ribbon Insert tab, click on PivotChart.
[image: Insert PivotChart]

If a cell within your data is active then your data should be selected automatically.  Specify where you want your chart and click OK.  A blank chart will appear.

In the PivotChart Field List, drag Type to the Axis box and Value to the Values box.  By default you will see a bar chart.  Right-click on the Chart Area and select Change Chart Type... and select Pie.

After manipulating chart components such as Legend, Title, Chart Area,, etc. you should be able to get to something like:

[image: Finished PivotChart]